# Why is the different "highest block" of --network id 3 and --testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, ropsten

I think both of --network id 3 and --testnet mean to the Ropsten network.

But, The result of "eth.syncing" differ from each.

--testnet result "highestBlock: 3852529"

```
$ geth --testnet console 2>> geth-test.log
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3788019,
  highestBlock: 3852529,
  knownStates: 18107905,
  pulledStates: 18107905,
  startingBlock: 3787849
}
```

--networkid 3 result "highestBlock: 6105050"

```
$ geth --networkid 3 console 2>> geth-test.log
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 1181005,
  highestBlock: 6105050,
  knownStates: 1529557,
  pulledStates: 1529557,
  startingBlock: 1181005
}
```

I do not know why this is the case...
Are not they the same?

Comment: Ropsten's network ID is 3, but setting just `--networkid 3` without `--testnet` will not put you on ropsten, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Geth and has been reported a while ago [on GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15574). `--networkid 3` brings to the mainnet.

If you want to connect a public test network, use

- `--testnet` for Ropsten
- `--rinkeby` for RinkeBy